# Does the Azure copy command - azcopy use TLS 1.2 protocol

Tags: azure, tls1.2, azcopy

This is regarding the copy of files from a linux server (on-premise) to the Azure storage account. We are using azcopy command.

We would like to know if the azcopy uses TLS 1.2 or not?

This is required to get security approvals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure storage(Including Azcopy) uses TLS 1.2 on public HTTPs endpoints but TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 are still supported for backward compatibility. More can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-security-tls